# Font awsome icons not showing

Tags: font-awesome

I am developing a webshop (www.kipos.nl). Since one day, suddenly the icons don't work any more.

I can see the cart in de header, but all the other icons are replaced with squares or with numbers.

The drop down arrows in de main menu are all numbers now.

I can't seem to fix this. I tried to add a line of code according to [this tutorial](https://www.theycallmehoz.com/font-awesome-not-working/), 
but this unfortunately doesn't work either.

Gabriela

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the Divi ETmodules font cannot be loaded. When you check the network tab in the dev console you can see that the following URL is "forbidden", yet it is necessary for a correct rendering:

```
https://kipos.nl/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf
```

Make sure your Divi WordPress theme is correctly installed, and the above file location is allowed access by the application server.

All this has little to do with programming, so please consult guides provided by Divi on how to verify the installation or redo it.